# Converting from RU/ML to AEU/ML

Tags: molecular-biology, pathology, elisa

I'd like to know whether it is possible to convert from RU/ml to AEU/ml.

I work in the ELISA department in our laboratory. We need to validate some kits by comparing results between our lab and another lab. They reported their values using the AEU/ml unit whilst ours are in RU/ml.

Is it possible to convert between AEU/ml and RU/ml?

RU: Relative Unit   AEU: Arbitrary Elisa Unit. The plates are read on a Biotek microplate absorbance reader via UV-VIS detection at a wavelength of 450.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For those that aren't familiar with the terms, can you please [edit] your post and define RU and AEU? Also, what format is the ELISA readout - colorimetric, luminescent, fluorescent, or MSD?

Comment: RU: Relative Unit   AEU: Arbitrary Elisa Unit. The plates are read on a Biotek microplate absorbance reader via UV-VIS detection at a wavelength of 450

Comment: How are these units calculated? If both labs run the same set of standards to plot a linear standard curve, you should be able to make a simple mathematical calculation to convert from one to the other.

Comment: For example, if a 1 μg/ml standard gives you 1000 RU and 5000 AEU, and a 5 μg/ml standard gives 3000 RU and 10,000 AEU, you can use curve-fitting to get the formulas for each line, then figure out a translation function. Alternatively, you can use their formula for determining AEU from the raw OD450 and back-calculate your own values.